# docker container dies after bash command and sql execution

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker, docker-compose

At first docker container boots up fine but soon after the delaye and execution of the schema.sql file, it disconnects and dies.

Maybe there's something wrong with `entry-point.sh` or following command line.

```
command: bash -c "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & chmod +x entry-point.sh && ./entry-point.sh"
```

**docker-compose.sql**

```
database:
  image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
  container_name: database
  ports:
    - 1433:1433
  volumes:
    - /var/opt/mssql
    - ./assets:/assets
  working_dir: /assets
  command: bash -c "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & chmod +x entry-point.sh && ./entry-point.sh"
  environment:
    SA_PASSWORD: "Password"
    ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

**entry-point.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#wait for the SQL Server to come up
sleep 10s

#run the setup script to create the DB and the schema in the DB
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Password -d master -i schema.sql
```

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE DataDemo;
GO

USE DataDemo;
GO
```

**Edit** tried different approaches but unable to set up database in docker with initialization script.

**Edit2**

following answer, Loader gave an error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as that `command:` finishes, the container exits.  In your case you're starting a background process and then running two commands.  Once those two commands complete the container is done; it doesn't matter that the background process is the thing you actually wanted the container to do.

Most of the standard database images provide some means to pre-populate application data; if I've found the right Dockerfile, [Microsoft's SQL server images](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/mssql-server-linux/Dockerfile) don't have this capability.  (The [PostgreSQL entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/b0251ccc21fa63851cb051458c669fbf37d26227/12/docker-entrypoint.sh#L124-L166) to do this is rather involved and I probably wouldn't try to replicate it on my own.)

One straightforward path to do this is to do the initialization in another container.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      - /var/opt/mssql
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
  loader:
    image: microsoft/mssql-tools:2017-latest
    volumes:
      - ./assets:/assets
    command: /assets/entry-point.sh
    restart: no
    environment:
      SA_HOST: database
      SA_PASSWORD: Password
```

(You could build a custom image that included the loader script instead of mounting it into the container, and use something more robust like the [wait-for-it script](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to check that the database is running.)

Comment: Thanks. `ERROR: manifest for microsoft/mssql-tools:2017-latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`, I'm using `image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools` instead, ok?

Comment: also `services.loader.restart contains an invalid type, it should be a string`, converted to `"no"`, is that right?